# Cross compilation of non c code

Tags: bazel

cross compiling a nearly empty workspace (no dependancies, one build file with an empty filegroup) on linux results in an error...

```
bazel build //... --cpu=x64_windows_msvc
ERROR: cc_toolchain_suite '@local_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for CPU 'x64_windows' and compiler 'cl'
```

Which means we can't cross compile non c languages without a valid c crosstool, this seems like a fairly fundamental limitation. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. C toolchain is part of the C configuration, and currently bazel doesn't work without valid C configuration.
2. Bazel can use tools during the build, many of which are in C, so even though your code doesn't need C toolchain, some tools that build your code do.

The 1. is a problem, we're working on it. But bazel tries hard to detect your toolchain, so in most cases there's no extra work needed. I'm wondering why it doesn't work for you... Investigating.

Comment: Bazel can detect a working host toolchain, and it would be sufficient to build tools used during the build, it's just insufficient to do cross compilation.

The repository was totally empty, the only files were:
*WORKSPACE*
```
workspace(name="test")
```
*BUILD.bazel*
```
filegroup(name="test")
```
So it should not have been trying to build anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bazel 0.21 Bazel doesn't require C toolchain unconditionally. It only loads the C toolchain when it is required by the build (e.g. building cc_binary, or using tools written in C++).